# How to use a single query to check if a value exists in two tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using EF Core 2.2.2, I have these two simple queries with the goal of determining if a `Color` is in use in either the `CollectionItem` or `PuzzleColor` table:

```
var isACollectionItem = _applicationDbContext.CollectionItem.Any(collectionItem => collectionItem.ColorId == color.Id);
var isAPuzzleItem = _applicationDbContext.PuzzleColor.Any(puzzleColor => puzzleColor.ColorId == color.Id);
var eitherOr = 
        _applicationDbContext.CollectionItem.Any(collectionItem => collectionItem.ColorId == color.Id)
    ||  _applicationDbContext.PuzzleColor.Any(puzzleColor => puzzleColor.ColorId == color.Id);
```

The first two lines generate two separate queries that look like:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [CollectionItem] AS [collectionItem]
        WHERE [collectionItem].[ColorId] = @__color_Id_0)
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END
```

Putting them together with an `||` operator means it will run both in the event the first isn't true, otherwise it will only run the first query.

Is it possible to merge both checks into a single query with EF?

Comment: Good question. One way it's run a query directly: _applicationDbContext.SqlQuery<bool>("your query"")
                            .FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @BasilKosovan True, I most likely could do that. I guess I was hoping to stick to LINQ if I could as I'm interesting in seeing how that would be done and I'm partial to the format.

Comment: We can join this table with condition which always returns true and after this use Any with two conditions. It should works but it is not looks smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a single query by using the `Color` table (that I did not include in my original post, my bad) as the starting point:

```cs
bool singleQuery = _applicationDbContext.Color
    .Any(myColor =>
            myColor.Id == _applicationDbContext.CollectionItem.FirstOrDefault(collectionItem => collectionItem.ColorId == color.Id).ColorId
        ||  myColor.Id == _applicationDbContext.PuzzleColor.FirstOrDefault(puzzleColor => puzzleColor.ColorId == color.Id).ColorId);
```

Which gets translated into:

```sql
SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Color] AS [myColor]
        WHERE ([myColor].[Id] = (
            SELECT TOP(1) [collectionItem].[ColorId]
            FROM [CollectionItem] AS [collectionItem]
            WHERE [collectionItem].[ColorId] = @__color_Id_0
        )) OR ([myColor].[Id] = (
            SELECT TOP(1) [puzzleColor].[ColorId]
            FROM [ServedColor] AS [puzzleColor]
            WHERE ([puzzleColor].[Discriminator] = N'PuzzleColor') AND ([puzzleColor].[ColorId] = @__color_Id_1)
        )))
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END
```

I imagine that a more performant query could be created by utilizing joins or unions though